# Jest and console.dir not displaying entire object

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, console.dir

I am trying to display an error within a Jest test but it won't show me all of the levels.

```
import util from 'util'

describe('Module', () => {
  it('should show all levels WITHOUT util', () => {
    const large = {
      level1: {
        level2: {
          message: 'At level 2!',
          level3: {
            message: 'At level 3!',
            level4: {
              message: 'At level 4!',
              level5: {
                message: 'At level 5!',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
    console.dir(large, { depth: 5 })
  })

  it('should show all levels with util', () => {
    const large = {
      level1: {
        level2: {
          message: 'At level 2!',
          level3: {
            message: 'At level 3!',
            level4: {
              message: 'At level 4!',
              level5: {
                message: 'At level 5!',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    }
    console.dir(util.inspect(large, { depth: 5 }))
  })
})
```

This gives me the following results

```
    { level1: { level2: { message: 'At level 2!', level3: [Object] } } } { depth: 5 }

    { level1:
       { level2:
          { message: 'At level 2!',
            level3:
             { message: 'At level 3!',
               level4:
                { message: 'At level 4!', level5: { message: 'At level 5!' } } } } } }
```

I was under the impression console.dir should do this for me already but the first test I'm getting `[Object]` after depth 2

I've even created a simple test outside of Jest and it seems to work as expected for console.dir, can anyone explain why this happens? Does Jest override how dir behaves with its own default depth or something?

```
const large = {
  level1: {
    level2: {
      message: 'At level 2!',
      level3: {
        message: 'At level 3!',
        level4: {
          message: 'At level 4!',
          level5: {
            message: 'At level 5!',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
console.dir(large, { depth: 5 })
```

Results in...

```
{ level1:
   { level2:
      { message: 'At level 2!',
        level3:
         { message: 'At level 3!',
           level4:
            { message: 'At level 4!', level5: { message: 'At level 5!' } } } } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

**tldr**; The second argument of `console.dir(value, options)` is ignored in the current Jest implementation.

---

Jest redefines the global `console` with its own implementation. Both in [`BufferedConsole`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/852819abc0de900f6d8ebb417e7d4fc3d7e647aa/packages/jest-console/src/BufferedConsole.ts#L101) and [`CustomConsole`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/852819abc0de900f6d8ebb417e7d4fc3d7e647aa/packages/jest-console/src/CustomConsole.ts#L78) you may find that `dir` method looks like this:

```
dir(firstArg: unknown, ...args: Array<unknown>): void {
  this._log('dir', format(firstArg, ...args));
}
```

It's hard to find the exact definition of the [`format`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-validate/src/utils.ts#L17) function, but Github suggests the following implementations:

[image]

```
export const format = (value: unknown): string =>
  typeof value === 'function'
    ? value.toString()
    : prettyFormat(value, {min: true});
```

[`prettyFormat`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/pretty-format#usage-with-options) has `maxDepth` option which is not passed in all 3 implementations.